# How to make responsive lines in path shape

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have these path lines, the form is okey with 2k res. and full hd but on other devices (smaller, bigger) the shape will not move responsive. Is there a way to make my code responsive or is there a more efficient way to do this.

Wished shape: [image: Lines]

```css
  .line {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .line span:first-child {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .line b {
    flex: 1 0 0;
    height: 5px;
    background: black;
    margin: 0 5px;
    min-width: 25px;
  }
  .line1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 5.2%;
    left: 36.2vw;
    top: 31.9%;
}
  .line2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 15%;
    left: 40vw;
    top: 20%;
}

.line3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 15%;
    left: 40vw;
    top: 45%;
}

.line4 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 26.1vh;
    left: 33.5%;
    top: 32.5%;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<p class="line line1"><span></span><b></b>
<p class="line line2"><span></span><b></b>
<p class="line line3"><span></span><b></b>
<p class="line line4"><span></span><b></b>
```

Comment: Why not make this an svg instead ? Then you have the responsiveness built in.

Comment: what are you trying to solve here? what is this shape for? Is it just this one shape? Are you trying to make a dynamic tree (e.g. a tournament) stretching as big as needed? If it's just this static image, why not use an image/svg and set its width/height proportionally?

Answer (score -1):

The general idea is to wrap all your lines into a `relative` container with height and width, so your lines are positioned according to their container. If your container is, in this case, the whole page, you will experiance those issues. I have put together some quick example.

```css
.container {
      position: relative;
      height: 500px;
    }  
    .container p {
      margin: 0;
    }
    .line {
      position: absolute;
      background: black;
    }
    .line1 {
      width: 75%;
      height: 5px;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
    .line2 {
      width: 25%;
      height: 5px;
      top: 50%;
      left: 0;
    }
    .line3 {
      width: 75%;
      height: 5px;
      right: 0;
    }
    .line4 {
      position: absolute;
      height: 500px;
      width: 5px;
      left: 25%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <p class="line line1"><span></span><b></b>
      <p class="line line2"><span></span><b></b>
      <p class="line line3"><span></span><b></b>
      <p class="line line4"><span></span><b></b>
    </div>
```

Please note that you will need to play a bit with the values in order to achieve the exact result as you want.